# How to do something to each element in the group

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe like so

```
a b c
1 2 3
1 3 4
1 4 5
2 5 6
2 6 7
3 7 8
4 8 9
```

What I want is the following:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 a
1 3 4 b
1 4 5 c
2 5 6 a
2 6 7 b
3 7 8 a
4 8 9 a
```

Essentially, I want to do a cycling, for each group by the column a, I want to create a new column which cycles the letters from a to z in order. Group 1 has three elements, so the letter goes from 'a' to 'c'. Group 3 and 4 has only 1 element, so the letter only gets assigned 'a'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A data.table option is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[, d:= letters[seq_len(.N)], by = a]
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is with a *split-apply-combine* paradigm, as in `plyr` (or `dplyr` or `data.table` or ...
Create data:

```
dd <- data.frame(a=rep(1:4,c(3,2,1,1)),
                 b=2:8,c=3:9)
```

Use `ddply` to split the data frame by variable `a`, transforming each piece by adding an appropriate variable, then recombine:

```
library("plyr")
ddply(dd,"a",
      transform,
        d=letters[1:length(b)])
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
library("dplyr")
dd %>% group_by(a) %>%
   mutate(d=letters[1:n()])
```

Or in base R (thanks @thelatemail):

```
dd$d <- ave(rownames(dd), dd$a, 
     FUN=function(x) letters[seq_along(x)] )
```

Comment: I thought when I do group by, R thinks I will have some kind of aggregation function for each group. Your answer opens many new opportunities for me. Thanks!